# Name and possibly a tutorial for this inset rounded rectangle technique

Tags: adobe-photoshop, photoshop-effects, effects

[image: The image]

I am speaking about the drop-in effect around the round edges. I like the fact that the actual theme seems to be a bit further back and the border is closer to the viewer.

I can gather that a portion of this must be using an inner shadow with black color.  Is this correct? How can I search this? I have spent quite a while now, but my non-existant background in design doesn't help.

I have access to photoshop but could use other tools if needed

Comment: You have my vote in favor of your teacher.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

It's pretty much simply a Bevel & Emboss layer style set to Emboss. An inner shadow helps a little bit. But depending upon your needs, the inner shadow may not be required.

[image: dropin]
[image: Gradient Overlay]
[image: Inner Shadow]
[image: Bevel and Emboss]

Comment: Ohhh thanks a lot, I wish I could give more votes!