# Photoshop inside empty effect?

Tags: adobe-photoshop, photoshop-effects

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Name and possibly a tutorial for this inset rounded rectangle technique](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/5735/name-and-possibly-a-tutorial-for-this-inset-rounded-rectangle-technique)

I'm looking for some special effect to accomplish in Photoshop for both text and a rectangle. Please have a look of below screen cast:

[image: Example image]

http://screencast.com/t/TSeeuWAfgMyh

You can see rectangle with some inside effect and seems empty area. Can anyone guide how to get this effect in Photoshop?

Comment: That's called a deboss, the inverse of an emboss. In the digital world it's also come to be known as an inner shadow.

Answer (score 0):

This effect is way easier with css, but I'll outline the photoshop technique for you.

Photoshop: 
You're going to need three layers for this. First layer is for the larger rectangle that contains the one in question.

1. Layer 1 > Fill with grey background color. Filter > Noise > Add Noise (5% uniform monochromatic). Double click layer to bring up layer style. Bevel and Emboss > 1px,  Inner Bevel, Chisel Soft, Angle: 90, Highlight Mode: Normal, 100%, uncheck use global light.
2. Layer 2 > Select the larger area of the internal rectangle with your rectangle marquee tool. Layer > Fill > White. Right click the first layer, select copy layer style. Right click the second layer, select paste layer style.  Set layer fill in the layers pane (directly under opacity) to 0%. Double click the layer to bring up the layer style pane. Check inner shadow (Distance:1(ish)px, Choke:33%, Size:7(ish)px, Quality Gaussian(The one that looks like a sloped hill), anti-aliased).
3. Layer 3 > Select the smaller area of the internal rectangle with your rectangle marquee tool. Edit > Fill > white. Set layer fill (or opacity) to 15%.
4. Done

Comment: CSS: {border-top:1px white; -moz-box-shadow: inset 0 0 10px black; -webkit-box-shadow: inset 0 0 10px black; box-shadow: inset 0 0 10px black;}

Comment: For the text do the same thing with the inner shadow, set layer fill to 0%.

Answer (score 0):

I believe the effect your after is something like this?

[image]

This effect is easily made in Photoshop:

1) Create your shape (or text) that you want to have this effect.

2) Lower the `Fill` to 0%

3) Open up the layer styles and apply the `Inner Shadow` & `Bevel and Emboss` effect, or any other effects you would like.

[image]

This creates a transparent shapes/text that has effects on it.