# How do I create a shape within a shape that has the same layer effects?

Tags: adobe-photoshop, shapes

I wish to create a bookmark shape within a bar shape and make it look like it is "part" of the underlying bar shape, i.e. It conforms to the same gradient, but is only a different color.

I created the below bookmark before I wished to do this. It is currently a smart object and also a raster image, so I am assuming it will be of no help.

My idea was to use the Pen tool to create a work path as part of the bar (using this existing bookmark as a template for the shape). I did this, but I was not sure where to go from there.

Any advice would be very much appreciated.

[image]

Comment: errrr.. huh? You mean you want the little hole in it? If that's the case, see here: http://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/8384/how-to-create-a-shape-in-a-form-of-two-basic-shapes-partially-substracted/8387#8387

Comment: Sorry I wasn't clear enough. I don't want a hole - let's say I want to keep the bookmark the same color as it is, but I want it to conform to the same gradient as the underlying layer. I assuming this bookmark itself (as it's raster) won't help, but I need to somehow carve another (bookmark-shaped) path into the underlying layer which I will then need to somehow make inherit the same gradient? By "same gradient," I mean, if the bookmark were the same color as the underlying bar and had no stroke, you would not be able to see it...

Comment: I'm still not really getting it. Can't you simply create a shape layer and lower the Fill slider in the Layers Panel to 0%?

Comment: I think it was a bad image - I've updated it. I want the bookmark to "belong" to the bar it is placed on by sharing its gradient, and perhaps looking like it is part of the bar itself - that is all. Apologies for not being clear enough.

Comment: I think I might understand your question now. Do you want the bookmark shape to have the same effect as the back button in your image?

Comment: Yes... :) Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay. Take a look at this question:

[Name and possibly a tutorial for this inset rounded rectangle technique](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/5735/name-and-possibly-a-tutorial-for-this-inset-rounded-rectangle-technique/5738#5738)

Basically the a very similar set up. The primary difference is in how the shape is filled and the blend mode for the gradient overlay.

[image: blend]
[image: bevel]
[image: inner shadow]
[image: gradient overlay]

the final image consisting of 2 layers. The red layer, then a vector layer for the rectangle with the above layer styles applied to it.

[image: inset]

This allows the inner shape to only adjust highlights and shadows so... if you alter the red layer, the shape changes as well...

[image: inset 1]

Of course, you can always tweak further to meet your specific needs.

Answer (score 0):

Make your bookmark shape a solid red color then change the blending option for the layer to color.

Answer (score 0):

I'd make an Hue/saturation adjustment layer with a mask the shape of your little bookmark (you can use a vector mask or a raster mask.

Then you can tweak the hue to your hearts content.